# How to draw a path between the perimeter of two circle using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an issue with d3.js and SVG. I want to draw a line between 2 circles, actually the line is between the center of each circle, but I want it to be between the perimeter of the two circles.

This is my D3.js code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var cx1 = '0px';
var cy1 = '50px';
var r1 = '3%';

var cx2 = '-200px';
var cy2 = '150px';
var r2 = '10.25px';

var urlImage = 'http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/circle-icons-add-on-2-by-martz90/png/128x128/playstation.png'


var svg = d3.select("svg")
   .attr('width','100%')
   .attr('height','100%')

var g = svg.append('g');

var pattern = svg.append('defs')
 .append('pattern')
 .attr('id','image')
 .attr('x','0%')
 .attr('y','0%')
 .attr('height','100%')
 .attr('width','100%')
 .attr('viewBox','0 0 128 128')
 
var image = pattern.append('image')
   .attr('x','0%')
   .attr('y','0%')
   .attr('height',128)
   .attr('width',128)
   .attr('xlink:href',urlImage);
 
   
var circle1 = g.append('g')
      .attr('id','PUESTO0')
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',cx1)
      .attr('cy',cy1)
      .attr('r','3%')
      .style('stroke-width',1)
      .style('stroke','green')
      .style('fill','url(#image)');
      
var circle2 = g.append('g')
      .attr('id','PUESTO1')
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',cx2)
      .attr('cy',cy2)
      .attr('r',r2)
      .style('stroke-width',6)
      .style('stroke','rgb(0, 0, 255)')
      .style('fill','white')
      
var line = g.append('line')
   .attr('x1',cx1)
   .attr ('y1',cy1)
   .attr('x2',cx2)
   .attr('y2',cy2)
   .style("stroke-width", 4)
   .style("stroke", "steelblue")

g.attr('transform','translate(' + 567.5 + ',' + 0 + ') scale(' + 1 + ')')

</script>
```

This is a screenshot showing the case:

[image]

Comment: If you're asking for help with D3, you should post D3 code, not rendered SVG elements.

Comment: You include your SVG markup, but not your code used to generate it. What have you attempted to do? Determining the points to draw the line between should be a pretty simple trigonometry problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the transparent of the image (.png), I fixed it by deleting the transparent using an external program.